# Prioritize one port forward over another

Tags: linux, networking, router, port-forwarding

I'm in the research stage of a small project related to priority port forwarding.

I've got a set of clients trying to reach a terminal server with some radios behind it.

The problem is that if the two clients hit the same target port on the terminal server, I see garbage data on the wrong client.

Say client A requests something from the target port, but client B was already requesting something, the device behind the terminal server on that port responds with the data it had queued up to send.

Note, the target port is the same for both clients.

I'd like to prioritize one of the servers, and so I want to implement a linux based sort of router app in between the 2 clients and the terminal server. 
The clients would each hit a different port, but the priority client, would get forwarded if it starts communicating. The other one would be blocked, stopped, halted or whatever.

I might've jumped the gun and developed a small python application that listens on 2 different ports and forwards the "priority" one to the terminal server. Blocking the forwarding of the "non-priority" port, until a certain amount of no comms happen in the priority port.

I've read about iptables, some NATing, socat, a little bit of QoS, etc., but I can't seem to find something out there for my problem.

I'm no networking expert, and have been using linux for about 2 years now, but I had never done much with this TCP/ip routing/forwarding scenarios, so I'd like to know if there's something out there, that could help me with prioritizing one port forward over the other, and that would be more efficient that a custom python app.

Thanks for any feedback.

Here's a small img, for reference of what I'm trying to do:

[Priority Forwarding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZUkd.png)

Comment: This is simply NOT how TCP/IP works and there is no chance that one system connecting to the same port is going to get data destined for another system. What you want is not priority port forwarding, if such a thing even exists. What you want is a solution to a problem caused by whatever you are calling “terminal server.” But you haven’t defined that. If the problem you mentioned existed, it would be absolutely impossible to run even a basic web server with more than one person connecting and the internet wouldn’t exist.

Comment: @Appleoddity It's a serial over IP server. So theres serial devices, being hosted on that terminal servers ports. As far as the problem being caused by the terminal server, that's not really the case, I dont think. The terminal server is just connecting its ports to the serial devices, which respond with queued data with whatever connects to them serially. That I think the best explanation I got haha. I'd just like for something to prioritize traffic to these devices and stop forwarding traffic from the other client in a somewhat dynamic way.

Comment: As Appleodity says, from a standards compliant tcp/IP stack, this can't happen at the IP level- it appears to be a limitation of the way the serial port is communicating with the TCP stack. The appropriate solution is to modify the serial port to lock access to the communicating IP until it's disconnected (and disconnect it if idle if appropriate). You might be able to write a serial port wrapper or modify the terminal emulator.

Comment: Isn't this exactly what socat and netcat are for?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can accomplish what you are trying to do with:

1. [socat](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html)
2. [GNU screen](https://linux.die.net/man/1/screen)
3. [TMUX](https://github.com/tmux/tmux/wiki)

As far as I know, you will have to rethink how these two terminals are connecting. I believe TMUX can sit in the middle as the app serving the two end client terminals. Something must multiplex the serial connections, there is no getting around that.

Here are some [Useful SOCAT commands](http://technostuff.blogspot.com/2008/10/some-useful-socat-commands.html)

I believe TMUX will be your best bet, here is a [getting started guide for tmux](https://www.howtoforge.com/sharing-terminal-sessions-with-tmux-and-screen)

I listed GNU screen because it seemed like it may be [useful](https://www.nixtutor.com/linux/introduction-to-gnu-screen/) in this scenario.

I also found a somewhat similar question to yours on serverfault.

https://serverfault.com/questions/797397/connect-two-ttys-via-tcp-ip